# Remove multiple localStorage items

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I have two 'localStorage' items, `summaryForm` and `projectForm`.

Currently I use two statements to remove them,

```
localStorage.removeItem("summaryForm");
localStorage.removeItem("projectForm");
```

Is it possible to join these two statements to one?

Comment: localSrorage.clear() will clear the entire localStorage if thats what you want

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Unfortunately that is not what I am looking for.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could just put the keys to remove in an array and loop over them:

```
let keysToRemove = ["summaryForm", "projectForm"];

for (key of keysToRemove) {
    localStorage.removeItem(key);
}
```

Using a full loop, or, using `forEach`:

```
keysToRemove.forEach(k =>
    localStorage.removeItem(k))
```

Or use `localStorage.clear()` if you want to just clear everything.

Comment: Or even `keysToRemove.forEach(k => localStorage.removeItem(k))` will work

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 Ya, I went back and forth between those two. I ended up deciding on a full loop instead. Maybe I'll toss that in too though. I just didn't want I bulk up the answer too much.

Comment: @Carcigenicate you just save my life , You are a real developer